# SQL Table Structure for frequent greater than and less than queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-design

I have to implement a table to frequently query for 'less than' and 'greater than' on 2 columns (xco, yco). For example, consider the following table

[image]

I would frequently fire a query like - give me all ids that have xco > 6. Or give me all ids that have yco < 9. xco and yco would change. But not so frequently.

What could be a good database design for such use case? I am expecting the number of rows to be between 10,000 to 50,000. I am currently trying AWS RDS since other parts of the system are on AWS. Would DynamoDB be any good for this case? I have pretty basic knowledge about SQL and almost none about NoSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any relational database will easily perform such queries.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id ...
    xco INT ...
    yco INT ...
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    INDEX(xco),
    INDEX(yco)
)
```

Then these can easily be done:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE xco > 6;
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE yco < 9;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I didn't knew I could index on xco and yco. I need to read about SQL optimization stuff. Just to be double sure, this would scale for 50,000 records?

Comment: 50 _thousand_ is trivial; 50 _billion_ would need further discussion.